# Python / Snakemake: check condition before executing

Tags: snakemake

Sorry for asking (please skip to bold letters for TLDR), but I have tried SO many search terms (10+) which all have led to completely unrelated topics for some reason. For example "snakemake execute code once at the beginning" leads to "how can I execute only a specific rule".

**What I want to know is really simple: how can I execute code ONCE** (no matter if being on a cluster or not, because I have read in the FAQ that global variables get executed multiple times in a cluster environment) **to ... just check something? That's all. For example: check if /etc/myfolder is empty. If empty, don't run the whole pipeline / exit the whole Snakefile.** Right at the beginning. I have sifted through the official tutorial and didn't find this part.

I'm aware that probably I could write that code just anywhere, because it gets executed before the rules, even if I place it at the bottom. But this probably doesn't work on a cluster ([FAQ](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v6.13.0/project_info/faq.html#why-do-my-global-variables-behave-strangely-when-i-run-my-job-on-a-cluster)). I need the code to be executed really only once. For the whole execution of the Snakefile. Also what do I do, if my check fails? Just sys.exit()? I'm looking for an example, but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want the [`onstart`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html) handler to execute something once at the start.  Alternatively you can put code above any of your rules to execute.  As you point out, this will run on each submitted job in cluster execution.  Something like creating a directory and allowing it to already exist is fine in either case.  Generating a new temp folder would be ok in `onstart` but may cause issues in 'bare' python code.

The other option, if you want to conditionally execute code, is to update your rule all to use an input function to check a condition and update the required files dynamically:

```
def all_input(wildcards):
    outputs = 'list of files you normally want'.split()
    if condition:
        outputs += 'more files if condition is true'.split()
    return outputs
rule all:
    input: all_input
```

This shouldn't affect job submissions unless you have other side effects, like creating temp files.

Comment: Thank you very much, onstart is exactly what I was searching for! Do you also know what I can do inside onstart (sys.exit() ?) to stop the whole pipeline? I mean in case some condition that I need is not met inside onstart. Also yesterday I continued to fiddle around and noticed that I could do this: instead of providing all final desired files as input to the all-rule, create an input function for the all-rule which either returns the output files or: nothing / empty list! With nothing, nothing happens, right? Or is that bad practice due to unwanted side effects that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You can sys.exit or raise an exception (I would use an exception).  Yes, if an input function returns nothing to all no files are targeted so nothing gets updated.  You could also have your logic to exit the pipeline contained in the input function so that if a condition is not met, you print a message and have the pipeline do nothing.  Only side effect may be with cluster execution, but due to how snakemake is run that is likely not an issue.